# how to manually set/persist a primary key in ORM Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

In my table primary key is ISBN so I need to set it manually when adding new Book in form. When adding new Book with ISBN `123`, it result in blank ISBN in database.

Entity:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="isbn", type="string", length=45)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $isbn;

public function setIsbn($isbn)
{
    $this->isbn = $isbn;
    return $this;
} 

public function getIsbn()
{
    return $this->isbn;
}
```

Form Type:

```
    $builder
        ->add('isbn')
```

Controller:

```
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
```

When adding new Book with ISBN 123

[image]

It result in blank ISBN in database (but not null, if that matters)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")` annotation, it is used to generate IDs, and you're providing them on your own.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to set identifier strategy to none，`@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="None")`

Comment: Just a small reminder it is uppercase NONE: `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")`